# Animation of an image moving off screen then back on

Tags: html, css

I have a png file of flags that I want to animate moving to the right side, off the screen then back onto the screen from the left side. Is there something in css that works for this specific purpose? or do I have to get creative with the design?

I have used keyframe animation to move the image from left to right so I can understand more about how animation works in css but I am still struggling.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Ufatrue.css">
    <title>Bashkorostan</title>
</head> 

  <body bgcolor="#E1E4E6"> 


      <div id="Top">
      <img src="Top.png" alt="7 Flags" align="middle">
          </div>

        <div id="Title">
    <h>Volga Federal District News</h>
    </div>

#Top {
    position: relative;
    animation: myanimation;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}
@keyframes myanimation {
    0% {left: -300px; top: 0px;}
    25% {left: -300px; top: 0px;}
    50% {left: 300px; top: 0px;}
    75% {right: -300px; top: 0px;}
    100% {right: 300px; top: 0px;}

}
```

Comment: include yout HTML please

Comment: Just added the HTML, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i understand exactly what you want. But take a look at the snippet below and please comment in the comment section below and tell me if this is what you wanted

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top {
  position: relative;
  animation: myanimation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes myanimation {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="top">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I apologise for not being clear, I want the image to move in a form of a loop going off the right side of the screen and coming back on the left side but without a gap between the image. An example I can think of is when an advertisement on TV has a text moving across the screen and when the text moves off the screen it feeds itself back through the side it first came through. Hope that helps

Comment: @JackSimpson can you check it now ? i changed the animation timing function

Answer (score 1):

You can use just marquee tag for HTML.

```css
.box{
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" direction="right" scrollamount="50" scrolldelay="1"><div class="box"></div></maruquee>
```

Comment: That's great I took away the the 'onmouseover' function and the out function and it's doing some of what I want it do, I was wondering if there's a way for the image to move continuously without a gap before it appears back on the screen like a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?: https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/tadyh6p9/14/

```
#Top {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    animation: myanimation;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes myanimation {
    0% { right: 0; }
    25% { right: -120%; }
    85% { visibility: hidden; }
    90% {
        left: -20%;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    100% {
      left: 0;
      }
}
```

Comment: Close but after the square moves off the screen I want it to come back in from the left.